# Groupby, filter, summarise and then apply the result to the whole column

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by, summarize

I am working with R and I have a series x at quarterly frequency and for which I want to extract the mean over the four quarters in 2012 and store that value in all rows of a newly created column. I have this kind of dataset

```
date durabl services 
2011-10-01 56.7 37.1
2012-01-01 68.1 90.6
2012-04-01 34.1 29.1
2012-07-01 22.56 34.12
2012-10-01 44.89 66.8
```

And I want to get to this

```
date durabl services base_durabl base_services
2011-10-01 56.7 37.1 42.4125 55.155
2012-01-01 68.1 90.6 42.4125 55.155
2012-04-01 34.1 29.1 42.4125 55.155
2012-07-01 22.56 34.12 42.4125 55.155
2012-10-01 44.89 66.8 42.4125 55.155
```

I tried using dplyr

```
df %>% group_by(year(date)) %>% filter(year(date)==2012) %>% mutate(base_durabl= mean(durabl),base_services=mean(services))
```

or with summarise but of course I just get a smaller tibble.

Comment: Why do you want the mean for 2012 also assigned to the row 1?

Comment: I basically want that mean to rebase the whole durabl and services series, meaning I want to divide the second and third column by the fourth and fifth, respectively. And I would need to do that in two steps, so first store the means of 2012 in new columns, then rebase the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply index the rows of `services` and `durabl` for which you want the mean estimated:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(base_durabl = mean(durabl[year(date)==2012]),
         base_services = mean(services[year(date)==2012]))
```

Output:

```
         date durabl services base_durabl base_services
1: 2011-10-01  56.70    37.10     42.4125        55.155
2: 2012-01-01  68.10    90.60     42.4125        55.155
3: 2012-04-01  34.10    29.10     42.4125        55.155
4: 2012-07-01  22.56    34.12     42.4125        55.155
5: 2012-10-01  44.89    66.80     42.4125        55.155
```

Comment: That makes sense, I don’t know why I wanted to use group_by haha. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way to @langtang's comprehensibly answer:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-date, ~mean(.[grep("2012", date)], na.rm=TRUE), .names = "base_{col}"))
```

```
        date durabl services base_durabl base_services
1 2011-10-01  56.70    37.10     42.4125        55.155
2 2012-01-01  68.10    90.60     42.4125        55.155
3 2012-04-01  34.10    29.10     42.4125        55.155
4 2012-07-01  22.56    34.12     42.4125        55.155
5 2012-10-01  44.89    66.80     42.4125        55.155
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
df[paste0("base_", names(df)[-1])] <- as.list(colMeans(subset(df, select = -date,
                 format(as.Date(date), "%Y") == "2012")))
```

-output

```
> df
        date durabl services base_durabl base_services
1 2011-10-01  56.70    37.10     42.4125        55.155
2 2012-01-01  68.10    90.60     42.4125        55.155
3 2012-04-01  34.10    29.10     42.4125        55.155
4 2012-07-01  22.56    34.12     42.4125        55.155
5 2012-10-01  44.89    66.80     42.4125        55.155
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2011-10-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-04-01", 
"2012-07-01", "2012-10-01"), durabl = c(56.7, 68.1, 34.1, 22.56, 
44.89), services = c(37.1, 90.6, 29.1, 34.12, 66.8)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```